# How to get the data after the users leave for payment and come back again

Tags: php, nusoap

I'm new to php, but technically I know it. as I've not done any projects yet with php and this is my first, I dont know which is the best way to handle this matter.

I have programmed a website which takes some regular information from the customer about books they want to print, to make an order and register it in a file to show the order either to the customer and to the website owner.

Till now I have done it well and orders would be registered and Emailed to the website owner and shown to the customer.The method which I followed for that was creating a form and on the submit the data was sent to a php file which had to handle the data and do the procedures.

But after that I tried to equip the website with a bank gateway to let the customer pay for his order. So he has to go to the bank and after success on payment he would be reffered to the website. Now I have to tell him what he has ordered and email the order to the site owner and make a file in the host to let the owner print that or set the track number on that.

I don't know how to get the data after the customer has left and then is back to the site. I'm now using POST method for sending the data to other php files.

Comment: you would have an id that is sent to the payment gateway, that would be returned by that gateway to validate  the transaction

Comment: yes. we know it as 'orderId'. but I want some more information when a customer is back. like the phone number, Email, order details, the address to send the order and etc...

Comment: then you should collect that information

Comment: But the bank wont give that. I dont register the information of the customers until their payment is done. I want that information which he filled before he leaves to the bank's gateway.

Comment: so store that information - i'm failing to see a problem here

Comment: standard process shop->checkout->provide address etc (you write this to db)->payment gateway(with id to match logged customer details)->customer back from payment gateway(providing that id - you log their payment)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.